# Why the content of <h:dataTable> is not refreshed afterb Ajax Action

Tags: ajax, jsf, primefaces

I am trying to update the contents of the dataTable after updating AJAX (triggering an Update request on DB)
in my program the user clicks on a commandLink or on a  to update an "odm.valide_manag1" field in the database (the request is executed with The Datatable changes the image (bullet) from red to green by testing this field unfortunately, this phase is not executed correctly the test always remains unchecked (no updating of the getter of the field)
I invoke the regeneration of the listodm object in the @PostConstruct, In the Getter, in the validation method, I changed the Scope without success

```
@ManagedBean 
@ViewScoped // or RequestScoped
public class listeOdm {
    public static Logger log=  LogManager.getLogger(listeOdm.class.getName());
    private List<odm> listOdm= new ArrayList<odm>() ; // a changer vers ListDataModel

    private odmService odmservice = new odmServiceImpl();
    FacesContext fc = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    HttpSession httpsession = (HttpSession) fc.getExternalContext().getSession(false);
    private String n_odm;
    private String operation;
    private HtmlDataTable dataTable;



    @PostConstruct
    public void initMyBean()
    {   listOdm=null;
        log.info("1- debut PostConstruct   :   "  );         
        listOdm = odmservice.findByMatricule("1000"); /*(String) httpsession.getAttribute("Matricule")*/
        //listOdm = odmservice.findAll();
        log.info("1- PostConstruct NOMBRE DES ODM  :   " + listOdm.size()+ "   The Object Is "+ listOdm.hashCode());
        RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().update("basicDT");
        /*  if("edit".equals(getParam("operation")))
        {
            editOdm();
        }*/
    }

    public String getParam(String name)
    {  
        Map<String, String> params=fc.getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap();
        return params.get(name);    
    }
    public void onValid_manag(RowEditEvent event)
    {
        odmservice.validManager(((odm) event.getObject()).getNum_odm());
       FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage("Odm validée", ((odm) event.getObject()).getNum_odm());
       FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg);
       // ((odm) event.getObject() ).setValide_manag1("2");
       // listOdm.clear();
       // listOdm = odmservice.findAll(); 
       listOdm = odmservice.findByMatricule("1000");
       log.info("2- on valid Method la nouvelle valeur de Valide_manage1 est :" + ((odm) event.getObject()).getValide_manag1());
       log.info("2- on valid Method  :   " + listOdm.size()+ "   The Object Is "+ listOdm.hashCode());
        RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().update("basicDT");
    }

        public void onCancel_manag(RowEditEvent event) {
              FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage("Odm Non validée", ((odm) event.getObject()).getNum_odm());
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg);
        }
    public void editOdm()
    {  // setN_odm(getParam("numOdm"));
       // setOperation(getParam("operation"));
        log.info("0- edit methode  :     "+getParam("numOdm"));
     odmservice.validManager(getParam("numOdm"));
        //listOdm = odmservice.findByMatricule("1000"); /*(String) httpsession.getAttribute("Matricule")*/
        log.info("edit de l'ODM  N°:   ");
       listOdm = odmservice.findByMatricule("1000");
    }
    public void modif()
    {    log.info("on Expand Start ");
         listOdm = odmservice.findByMatricule("1000");
    }
    public void printOdm()
    {}
    public List<odm> getListOdm() {
        log.info("getter list odm"+this.listOdm.hashCode());
        if (FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getRenderResponse()) {
            log.info("getter list odm"+this.listOdm.hashCode());
            listOdm = odmservice.findByMatricule("1000");
        }
        return listOdm ;//= odmservice.findByMatricule("1000");
    }

    public void setListOdm(List<odm> listOdm) {
        this.listOdm=listOdm ;
    }

    public String getN_odm() {
        return n_odm;
    }

    public void setN_odm(String n_odm) {
        this.n_odm = n_odm;
    }

    public String getOperation() {
        return operation;
    }

    public void setOperation(String operation) {
        this.operation = operation;
    }

    public HtmlDataTable getDataTable() {
         dataTable.clearInitialState();
        return dataTable;
    }

    public void setDataTable(HtmlDataTable dataTable) {
        this.dataTable = dataTable;
    }

}
```

the Xhtml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core">
<h:head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" />
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet"></link>
<title>Insert title here</title>

</h:head>
<h:body>
    <ui:debug />

     <h:form id="formulaire1">
     <h:inputHidden value="#{listeOdm.n_odm}" />
     <h:inputHidden value="#{listeOdm.operation}" />
     <p:growl id="msgs" showDetail="true"/>
    <h:dataTable  id="basicDT"    var="odm" value="#{listeOdm.listOdm}" binding="#{listeOdm.dataTable}"      >

       <h:column headerText="Etat" id= "bulet">

         <h:panelGroup rendered="#{odm.valide_manag1 eq '2'}">
         <h:graphicImage   library="img" name="if_bullet-green_44189.png" width="24" height="24" style="border-style: none"/>
         </h:panelGroup>
         <h:panelGroup rendered="#{odm.valide_manag1+odm.valide_manag2 eq '1'}">
          <h:graphicImage   library="img" name="orange.gif" width="24" height="24" style="border-style: none"/>
         </h:panelGroup>
          <h:panelGroup rendered="#{odm.valide_manag1+odm.valide_manag2 eq '0'}">
          <h:graphicImage   library="img" name="if_bullet-red_44191.png" width="24" height="24" style="border-style: none"/>
         </h:panelGroup>
         </h:column>
           <h:column headerText="valid">
            <h:outputText value="#{odm.valide_manag1}" />
        </h:column>
        <h:column headerText="Num Odm">
            <h:outputText value="#{odm.num_odm}" />
        </h:column>
        <h:column headerText="Client">
            <h:outputText value="#{odm.client}" />
        </h:column>
        <h:column headerText="Station">
            <h:outputText value="#{odm.station}" />
        </h:column>
         <h:column headerText="Destination">
            <h:outputText value="#{odm.destination}" />
        </h:column>
        <h:column headerText="date dep">
            <h:outputText value="#{odm.date_dep}" pattern="dd/MM/yyyy"/>
        </h:column>
        <h:column headerText="date retour">
            <h:outputText value="#{odm.date_ret}" pattern="dd/MM/yyyy"/>
        </h:column>
        <h:column headerText="Cient">
            <h:outputText value="#{odm.client}" />
        </h:column>
         <h:column headerText="Edit" width="24">

               <h:commandLink    
                    actionListener="#{listeOdm.editOdm}" update=":formulair1:basicDT"   ajax="true">
                    <f:param name="numOdm" value="#{odm.num_odm}"></f:param>
                    <f:param name="operation" value="edit"></f:param>
                    <h:graphicImage   library="img" name="118805-128.png" width="24" height="24" style="border-style: none"/>
                    <!--  <i class="fa fa-envelope"></i> -->

                </h:commandLink>
                <h:commandLink    
                    actionListener="#{listeOdm.printOdm}" update="formulaire1">
                    <f:param name="numOdm" value="#{odm.num_odm}"></f:param>
                    <f:param name="operation" value="edit2"></f:param>
                    <h:graphicImage   library="img" name="Print-2-128.png" width="24" height="24" style="border-style: none"/>
                    <!--  <i class="fa fa-envelope"></i> -->
                </h:commandLink>
        </h:column>

    </h:dataTable>

    </h:form>

</h:body>
</html>
```

JSF2.2.9 Tomcat 8.5

Comment: Can you make proper sentences? This is too hard to read.

Comment: excuse me i m french speaking

Comment: I am trying to update the contents of the dataTable after  an AJAX call

Comment: I am trying to update the contents of   h:dataTable  by cliking on  AJAX button or link (wich triggering an Update request on DB) in my program the end user clicks on a commandLink or on a Commandbutton to update a  field "odm.valide_manag1"  in the database (in The h:Datatable the image (bullet) changes from red to green by testing this field) unfortunately, this phase is not executed correctly the EL expression  odm.valide_manag1+odm.valide_manag2 eq '0' is always eq 0 (no updating of the getter of the field odm.valide_manag1;odm.valide_manag2) I invoke the regeneration of the listodm object

Comment: *"excuse me i m french speaking"*. Nonsense. French has the same capitalization and punctuation rules as English. Sentences start with a capital and end with a period in both English and French. This is just sloppy and disrespectful writing, not professional writing. Even if you wrote in French, people would call you on that. We don't care about grammar. We however do care about readability. Readability has very little to do with grammar. Readability has very much to do with proper formatting. You as a programmer should know that. Bad formatted code is also barely readable.

Comment: Learn the technology you use, you are mixing PrimeFaces attributes on plain jsf components and are effectively nowhere using ajax. And `RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().update("basicDT");` in a `@postconstruct` is not very common...

Comment: Hi everybody,
Mr BalusC it's honor for me to see your commentary. thank you for all the knowledge in programming that you taught me through your posts. You are my master.
Mr Kukeltje, the use of RequestContext was just for the test, and my real project is in PF 6.1, to test if  that is not caused by a bug in PF.
Note: I applied the @BalusC tutorial on debugging JSF lifecycle, I note that nothing happens in phsase 6 (Rendering); the whole action takes place in phase 5 (invoking app).This problem makes me crazy, please put me on the path of the solution. Thanks!

Comment: @BalusC , can you help me please ?

Comment: Note: The dataTable does not have an id attribute in the HTML render, is  this normal?

Comment: Any help please !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved my problem  !!!!!.
I want to share this experience with beginners, because for an expert it is  obvious.
the rows of the DataTable are Objects, the execution of the  listner or the  command `<p:ajax event="rowEdit" listener="#{listeOdm.onValid_manag}"  update=":formulaire1:basicDT"/>`
 updates the record in the DB without updating the Datatable Row.

```
public void onValid_manag(RowEditEvent event)
{
   odmservice.validManager(((odm) event.getObject())); // herer was my error, before i passed a string  instead of the object  event.getObject().getNum_Odm
   listOdm = odmservice.findByMatricule("1000");   
}
```

and in the methode invoking Hibernate Update i updated the record in the DB like this

```
public void validManager(String num_odm)
  {

     session.beginTransaction();
     Query q = session.createQuery("update odm set valide_manag1='2' where num_odm = :num_odm");
     q.setParameter("num_odm",num_odm);
     q.executeUpdate();
      session.getTransaction().commit();
    }
```

the correct method is :

```
public void validManager(odm odm) { //object in the selected row as parameter
     session.beginTransaction();
// updating the object in memory  
     odm.setValide_manag1("2");
//hibernate execute the update query  in DB
     session.save(odm);
     session.getTransaction().commit();
}
```

Comment: Hi, is there any global solution, where the object and the record in DB are updated simultaneously ?